# Where are the snow boots?

Tags: opus-rocket-of-whispers

It seems impossible to find snow boots in *OPUS: Rocket Of Whispers*, which means I can't complete Rocket 13.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you figure it out? Go north west should be a snow trail. A walkie talkie symbol should show up on your screen. It's the witch and she gets the ghost to clear a trail for you to the place you can loot some boots.